# Cannot remap gr in ideavim

Tags: rider, remap, ideavim

I'm trying to create some mappings for my ideavim plugin in Rider -

I tried to map gr to action RenameElement, but for some reason, it takes no effect.
I want the mapping to be effective only in normal mode.
Here's my current mapping:

```
nmap gr <Action>(RenameElement)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the answer:

The mapping :

```
nmap gr <Action>(RenameElement)
```

Is correct, however, after editing the .idearc file you have to press reload on this thingy here:

[image]